# Set a global variable when an android notification is taped

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need to set

```
((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).globalVar(true);
```

When a user taps

```
private void sendNotification2(String msg) {

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mainIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                    /*.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))*/
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_2, mBuilder.build());
    //mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    //mBuilder.flags |= mBuilder.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
}
```

Basically that it's all. I need to set that global variable when the user taps the notification

Answer (score 1):

You can do this workaround:

1.Add an extra to your `intent`

```
mainIntent.putExtra("from_notification", true);
```

2.Check it in your activity, if it was set, do the `this.getApplication()).globalVar(true);`

in your activity `onCreate`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.hasExtra("from_notification") && intent.getBooleanExtra("from_notification")) {
    ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).globalVar(true);
}
```

Comment: Note that this is also influenced by the 'launchMode' of the activity,  if it's 'singleTop' for instance it will call the onNewIntent() instead of onCreate(). More info at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Singleton pattern to create a 'global variable'. Wikipedia has a good article on a [thread-safe implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Initialization_On_Demand_Holder_Idiom%20-and-%20http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom]). However, this might be excessive for your needs. Why do you need to set a global boolean?

EDIT:

```
public class Singleton {
    // this private member variable is used in my example getter and setter below:
    private boolean mIsLoggedIn = false;

    private Singleton() {}
    private static class Holder { private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton(); }

    protected static Singleton getInstance() { return Holder.INSTANCE; }

    // Getters and Setters for your global variable(s)
    // Examples:
    protected boolean getIsLoggedIn() { return mIsLoggedIn = isLoggedIn; }
    protected void setIsLoggedIn(boolean isLoggedIn) { mIsLoggedIn = isLoggedIn; }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Fair enough.
See my edited answer above, please remove the downvote. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds good ;)   General rule for stack overflow...links are great and all but over time they tend to get broken as pages get repointed.  We want SO to be inclusive...all the information you need to answer this question should be here.  Do an edit.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: I will remember this for the future and refrain from link-only posts. Thank you.